# A better way to write this React Class Component with Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a section with a fixed height. I don't know when the component mounts (first renders) whether the content coming in will fit or not. If it does NOT fit, then I need to render a 'Read More' button.

It looks like this:
[image]

I wrote this originally as a Class component using the lifecycle methods DidMount/DidUpdate:

### Class Component

```
import React, { createRef } from "react"
import styled from "@emotion/styled"

import Section from "../Section"
import ButtonReadMore from "./ButtonReadMore"
import Paragraphs from "./Paragraphs"

const StyledHeightContainer = styled.div`
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
`

class ParagraphList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    overflowActive: false,
  }
  wrapper = createRef() // so we can get a ref to the height container

  isOverflowing(el) {
    if (el) return el.offsetHeight < el.scrollHeight
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ overflowActive: this.isOverflowing(this.wrapper.current) })
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.wrapper.current && !this.state.overflowActive) {
      this.setState({
        overflowActive: this.isOverflowing(this.wrapper.current),
      })
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ overflowActive: false })
  }

  render() {
    const { moreButtonText, titleText, paragraphs, theme } = this.props

    return (
      <>
        <Section overflowActive={this.state.overflowActive}>
          {this.state.overflowActive || !this.wrapper.current ? (
            <StyledHeightContainer ref={this.wrapper}>
              <Paragraphs paragraphs={paragraphs} />
            </StyledHeightContainer>
          ) : (
            <Paragraphs paragraphs={paragraphs} />
          )}
        </Section>
        {overflowActive ?
         <ButtonReadMore
           onClicked={handleClick.bind(this)}
           moreButtonText={moreButtonText}
           theme={theme}
         />
        : null}
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default ParagraphList
```

My best way to explain the flow:

1. When the component mounts, the flag is false and we have no reference to the div so the `StyledHeightContainer` will try to render and thus provide a ref to it
2. In `componentDidMount` -> try to set the overflow flag (which will be false because at this point we do not yet have rendering completed so the ref will be null). But by setting the flag anyway, we queue an additional render pass
3. 1st INITIAL rendering completes -> we have a ref to the div now
4. The 2nd (queued) render occurs, firing the `componentDidUpdate` -> we can calculate the overflow and set the flag to true when the content overflows
5. When the user clicks the button -> set the flag to false, which will trigger a re-render and hence the `StyledHeightContainer` will be removed from the DOM.

### Functional Component With Hooks

[Sandbox of the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-using-hooks-in-section-component-xrle0?file=/src/ParagraphList.js)

When I re-wrote this as a functional component using Hooks, I ended up with this:

```
import React, { createRef, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import styled from "@emotion/styled"

import Section from "../Section"
import ButtonReadMore from "./ButtonReadMore"
import Paragraphs from "./Paragraphs"

const StyledHeightContainer = styled.div`
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
`

const ParagraphList = ({ moreButtonText, titleText, paragraphs, theme }) => {
  const [overflowActive, setOverflowActive] = useState(false)
  const [userClicked, setUserClicked] = useState(false)
  const wrapper = createRef(false) // so we can get a ref to the height container

  const isOverflowing = el => {
    if (el) return el.offsetHeight < el.scrollHeight
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userClicked && !overflowActive && wrapper.current) {
      setOverflowActive(isOverflowing(wrapper.current))
    }
  }, [userClicked]) // note: we only care about state change if user clicks 'Read More' button

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOverflowActive(false)
    setUserClicked(true)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Section theme={theme} overflowActive={overflowActive}>
        {!userClicked && (overflowActive || !wrapper.current)  ? (
          <StyledHeightContainer ref={wrapper}>
            <Paragraphs paragraphs={paragraphs} />
          </StyledHeightContainer>
        ) : (
          <Paragraphs paragraphs={paragraphs} />
        )}
      </Section>
      {overflowActive ?
        <ButtonReadMore
          onClicked={handleClick.bind(null)}
          moreButtonText={moreButtonText}
          theme={theme}
        />
        : null}
    </>
  )
}

export default ParagraphList
```

I was surprised that I needed to add another state (userClicked), which is how I force the 2nd render to occur (ie. the equivalent to the `componentDidUpdate` in the class solution).

Is this correct or can someone see a more concise way to write the 2nd solution?

**NOTE**

One of the reasons I ask is because in the console I get this warning:

> ```
> 48:6  warning  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies:
> 'overflowActive' and 'wrapper'. Either include them or remove the
> dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
> ```

and I don't *THINK* I want to add them to the dependency array, as I don't want to trigger rendering when they change...?

Comment: Can you please create a code sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/) or something for your 2nd approach?
It will be easier for me to refactor it then if needed.

Comment: Ok, I can try. Give me some time as I've not done that before for React

Comment: It will be simple, just create an example/mock for this code. So that we can have something to play with :)

Comment: @ManishSundriyal I added the code, but since all the data is loaded dynamically from GraphQL queries, the code won't run in the Sandbox without me mocking all the data

Comment: @ManishSundriyal OK, got it working in Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-using-hooks-in-section-component-xrle0?file=/src/ParagraphList.js

Comment: great question. A few more minutes :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211450/discussion-between-manish-sundriyal-and-rmcsharry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really enjoyed while solving the query.

Here is the implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-using-hooks-in-section-component-5gibi?file=/src/ParagraphList.js

First of all, I was thinking of

```
useEffect(() => {
  setOverflowActive(isOverflowing(wrapper.current));
}, [wrapper]);
```

But if we do this, it will again call the useEffect as when we'll click on the Read more button. Because it was comparing the reference of the wrapper and not it's value.

So, to avoid the reference comparison we have to use the useCallback hook.

```
 const isOverflowingNode = node => {
    return node.offsetHeight < node.scrollHeight;
  };

  const wrapper = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setOverflowActive(isOverflowingNode(node));
    }
  }, []);
```

I came across the beautiful discussion: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14387

For more information:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node

Thanks for the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra `useEffect(() => (...),[])` that acts like `componentDidMount()`. And another `useEffect(() => (...))` that acts like `componentDidUpdate()`. Then you should be able to get rid of `userClicked`.

This is a good link on how the lifestyle methods work with hooks. https://dev.to/trentyang/replace-lifecycle-with-hooks-in-react-3d4n

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setOverflowActive(isOverflowing(wrapper.current));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!overflowActive && wrapper.current) {
      setOverflowActive(isOverflowing(wrapper.current))
    }
  });
```

The second one might need to be `useLayoutEffect` if you are wanting the update to happen after the layout.

Comment: Thanks, nice idea but sadly that doesn't work (even with useLayoutEffect) - and the console warns about infinite chain of events :(